# css drop down menu not working on iphone/ipad

Tags: php, javascript, iphone, css, ipad

I'm using a css based drop-down menu on my site which doesn't appear to be compatible with iphones/ipads.

I believe it might be something to do with the fact that the menu is supposed to appear on hover, but of course iphones are touch screen. However it does work on android by clicking the where you would normally hover and the drop-down appears.

Unfortunately I have no iAnything and so testing is down to the kindness of my friend who's not always available.

the plugin is from:
http://www.zen-cart.com/downloads.php?do=file&id=353

my implementation is at:
http://www.traditionalirishgifts.com/

and a version I'd love to see whether it works or not but I'm iLess at the moment is:
**EDIT**: oops go the wrong url - here it is - http://makeupconnection.com

Has anyone any ideas on how to sort this so it appears onclick as well? Or at least just behaves the same way on iphone as on android

thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at this example on drop-down menu suitable for iphone/ipad: http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/cssplay-ipad-dropdown-menu-fixed.html

Comment: Hi thanks for that but I really need to just make this menu work asap. I'll definitely be checking your one out next time over though.